# How to make strings of superscript variables?

Tags: c#, string, unicode, char, superscript

How to make strings of superscript variables?
I have a class called Part (a part of a polynom) which has the properties
a (coeffiecient)
and n (exponent).
I want to make a method that returns a string of:
string.Format(a+"X"+(n as an exponent))
how can I write here n as an exponent in superscript as a variable?

Comment: I do not think it is possible in normal text.  It may be possible using Rich Text format.  Where do you want to display these superscripts ?

Comment: in a console application in C#... perhaps also in windows forms